# Passing token in Flutter from auth to http-request

Tags: flutter, dart

how to pass the token value from above code to another screen into a http-request as variable.

```
class AppStarted extends AuthenticationEvent {}

class LoggedIn extends AuthenticationEvent {
  final String token;

  const LoggedIn({@required this.token});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [token];

  @override
  String toString() => 'LoggedIn { token: $token }';

}
```

Thank you for your help, haning on this for 2 hours now...

Comment: Please post the other half of your code, where you want to pass or extract thee token.

Comment: can you give more details of your code ?

Comment: @BigWatanga On other page i do a simple http request where i need the token variable. The Problem is, that the code is to much to share.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad On other page i do a simple http request where i need the token variable. The Problem is, that the code is to much to share.

Comment: What we meant, are you capturing the token in the other page? and trying to send it here? We dodn't need your token, nobody is interested in the secret token, but we have to know the method you are persuing in order to help you debug your prolblem.

Answer (score 1):

`first create a class where your where https request handle & token store`

```
class Network {
      var  token;
    final string base= "/api";
     //token get when needed 
 _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('data'));
     token = user['token'];
     }

    //signup 
  signUp(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = baseUrl + apiUrl;
    return await http.post(fullUrl,
    body: jsonEncode(data), headers: _setHeaders());
    }

  //login
   signIn(apiUrl) async {
   var fullUrl = baseUrl + apiUrl;
    await _getToken();
     return await http.get(fullUrl, headers: _setHeaders());
   }

  }
```

`in sign up page use this method where you use sign up button on pressed`

```
void _signUp() async {

var data = {
  'mobile': mobileController.text,
  'password':  mobileController.text,
};

var res = await Network().signUp(data, '/register');
var body = json.decode(res.body);
if (body.statusCode == 200) {
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(body['data']['token']));

  localStorage.setString('data', json.encode(body['data']));

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
  );
} else  {
//      errorMessage = "as you want to show ";

 
}


  }
```

`in sign up page , use this method same as sign up pages`

```
void signIn() async {

var data = {'mobile': mobile, 'password': password};
var res = await Network().signIn(data, '/login');
var body = json.decode(res.body);

if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(body['data']['token']));
  localStorage.setString('data', json.encode(body['data']));
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
  );
} else if (res.statusCode != 200) {
 // mobileError = "These credentials do not match our records.";
}
   }
```

`now you can have the token when u signup/singIn and store token in sharedSharedPreferences` 
`whenever you try to acces token just called _getToken()  method`